# How can I create a link in an angular app that loads inside a tab?

Tags: angularjs, tabs

I have a link in an angular app that looks like this:

```
<tab ng-controller="childCtrl" heading="Children">
 <a href="#/parent/{{parent.Id}}/child/{{child.Id}}">edit</a>
</tab>
```

How can I load the link inside the tab instead of refreshing the entire view?

Comment: wish I could downvote this comment

Comment: I've deleted the comment as it bothers you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like other approach with one point of handling all routes. ui.router with nested views allows to do it.

**Template**

```
<div ><a ui-sref="home.tab1" >Tab1</a></div>
<div><a ui-sref="home.tab2" >Tab2</a></div>
<br>
<div ui-view="tabs"></div>
```

**app**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.router']);
  app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
        virtual: true
      })
      .state('home.tab1', {
        url: '/tab1',
        views: {
          tabs: {
            templateUrl: '1.html'
          }
        }

      })
      .state('home.tab2', {
        url: '/tab2',
        views: {
          tabs: {
            templateUrl: '2.html'
          }
        }
      });
      $urlRouterProvider
      .otherwise('/home/tab1');
  })
```

And demo http://plnkr.co/edit/r1jPgkMnPAMlI34gZrMA?refresh&p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You could define the path to the selected tab's content when the link is clicked, and use [`ng-include`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) to display it.

```
<div ng-repeat="parent in parents">
  <div ng-repeat="child in parent.children">
    <a href="" ng-click="selectPath(parent, child);">
      Parent {{parent.Id}}, Child {{child.Id}}
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div ng-include="selected.path"></div>
```

Here is a demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/7SPnluxUfcNNQDyeC6yt?p=preview

Comment: this is really interesting!